# Is ASP.NET MVC flexible?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, kigg

Can it easily be combined with jQuery, (ASP.NET) Ajax, ASP.NET webforms, other frameworks.
What about pulling dynamic code from ASP.NET MVC into for example classic ASP?

Does the MVC model mean that it is easy to customize code?

Background:

1. I have some experience that it can lead to problems to integrate frameworks relying on JavaScript with each other?
2. We have a classic ASP where we write new stuff in ASP.NET, and include .aspx code in the ASP files.
3. I am looking for some OS frameworks for stuff we need, and i think MVC based ones should be easier to adopt (KIGG)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC ships with jQuery as the default javascript framework, so no worries there.  There aren't really any ties in the framework itself to jQuery so you could also switch it out with a framework of your choice.  MVC comes with it's own AJAX implementation that builds on the base ASP.NET Ajax implementation (at least in javascript), so there is AJAX support but I think you'll find that it's different -- no UpdatePanels, for instance -- but you're able to do similar things.

You can mix WebForms with MVC, but you'll need to set up IgnoreRoutes for those URLs so they don't get processed.  I confess that I haven't found a need to do this yet, but then I don't use third-party controls.  That might be an area where, at least for now, you still need some WebForms.  I've never used classic ASP and likely won't so I can't help you there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any Javascript framework with MVC, they have included Jquery as the default but any can work with it.

As far as flexibility, we have deployed a working site with ASP.NET webforms, MVC and .NET 1.1 libraries, so yes it is flexible.

In our experience ASP.NET MVC is the best thing MS have done for web development, especially if you like to control closely your html output and use web standards in your layout and design. We have used it for 6 Months and we are NEVER going back to web forms.

Have fun!